# how to remove the special characters in a file using shell

Tags: shell

I am having a file content like below:

EP1.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â        NV Energy currently offers a program called Equal Payment Plan in which your household<92>s total electricity costs for the entire aged across your twelve monthly bills so that each bill is approximately the same throughout the year.
EP2.Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â        Does your household currently participate in  Equal Payment Plan?

How can I remove the Â character.
I tried using sed:
sed 's/Â//g' it is not working.
 but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround:
Instead of trying to replace wrong charaters You can try to do the opposite operation which is replace everything except good charaters:

```
's/[^A-Z0-9]//g'
```

Of course You need to include in this list other characters You want to keep: dots, commas, brackets.